# Live Jquery Extension or Chrome Developer Feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use an absolutely brilliant Live CSS tool called User CSS, this allows you to run CSS live in the browser and is so handy.

I am looking for something similar for Jquery (or even Javascript). Does a live Chrome extension exist or perhaps a feature in Chrome Developer tools that allows me to run Jquery function after I have done some tinkering using Inspect Element on that single page before I refresh it and restore it to its original form?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. Console in Chrome allows you to run any js you like.

Comment: You can use the Console in Chrome to fire JavaScript functions from the command line, see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en